# Swift CustomStringConvertible with complex type

Tags: swift

I want CustomStringConvertible to provide me with a description of a node, specifically the edges it contains.

For background I've been working on graph theory and have created a node:

```
class Node : CustomStringConvertible {
    // unique identifier required for each node
    var identifier : Int
    var distance : Int = Int.max
    var edges = [Edge]()
    var visited = false

    var description: String {
        return "identifier: " + identifier.description + ", Edges: " + ( "edgesString" )
    }

    init(visited: Bool, identifier: Int, edges: [Edge]) {
        self.visited = visited
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.edges = edges
    }

    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}
```

with edges

```
class Edge {
    var from: Node // does not actually need to be stored!
    var to: Node
    var weight: Int
    var description : String {
        return "from: " + from.description + ", to: " + to.description + ", weight: " + weight.description
    }
    init(to: Node, from: Node, weight: Int) {
        self.to = to
        self.weight = weight
        self.from = from
    }
}
```

I can easily print out each edge for each node

> testGraph.nodes.forEach { $0.edges.forEach{ print ($0.description)}}

However I've not been able to implement the in by description of the node.

I tried to write the equivalent to my for each statement

```
var description: String {
    var edgesString = String()
    edges.forEach{  edgesString.append($0.description)}
    return "identifier: " + identifier.description + ", Edges: " + ( edgesString )
}
```

but execution gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in this case, in fact I cannot get any code to complete and give me the description of the node and the edges contained within.

How can I complete my description string for the node, that then goes on to describe the edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `description` code can cause infinite roop with `Node.description` and `Edge.description`.

`Node` call `Edge.description` for each edge, and `Edge` call `Node.description` for its from and to nodes. if the graph has circular connection, not star, it will cause infinite roop.

A simple way is that `Edge.description` only show `Node.identifier` instead of deteiled description.

```
class Edge {
    var from: Node // does not actually need to be stored!
    var to: Node
    var weight: Int
    var description : String {
        return "{ Edge, from: \(from.identifier), to: \(to.identifier), weight: \(weight) }"
    }
    init(to: Node, from: Node, weight: Int) {
        self.to = to
        self.weight = weight
        self.from = from
    }
}
class Node : CustomStringConvertible {
    // unique identifier required for each node
    var identifier : Int
    var distance : Int = Int.max
    var edges = [Edge]()
    var visited = false

    var description: String {
        let edgesString = edges.map { $0.description }.joined(separator: ", ")
        return "{ Node, identifier: \(identifier), Edges: [\(edgesString)] }"
    }

    init(visited: Bool, identifier: Int, edges: [Edge]) {
        self.visited = visited
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.edges = edges
    }

    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}

let rootNode = Node(visited: false, identifier: 10, edges: [])
var edges: [Edge] = []
for i in 0..<3 {
    let node = Node(visited: false, identifier: i, edges: [])
    let edge = Edge(to: node, from: rootNode, weight: i)
    edges.append(edge)
}
rootNode.edges = edges

print(rootNode)
// { Node, identifier: 10, Edges: [{ Edge, from: 10, to: 0, weight: 0 }, { Edge, from: 10, to: 1, weight: 1 }, { Edge, from: 10, to: 2, weight: 2 }] }
```

And if you want to search and print all nodes, you'd better to make another function to do that.

It should remember which node you've already visited (or use `visited` member, if you can), and try not to visit those visited nodes.

Comment: Yes, you're right caused an infinite loop. Also not using string interpolation seems to cause performance problems...so thanks.